# New-WebApplication fails to create a browsable WebApplication

Tags: powershell, iis

I am running the following script to create a WebApplication.

```
New-WebApplication -Name "PreviewApp" -Site "MySite" -ApplicationPool "MySite" -PhysicalPath "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/previewapp"
```

That PS command seems to work as it display details about the newly created web application.

```
Name             Application pool   Protocols    Physical Path
----             ----------------   ---------    -------------
PreviewApp       MySite             http         c:/inetpub/wwwroot/previewapp
```

However, when I try to browse to my app, IIS gives me a `404 Error` without further information.

What is strange is that I tried to create the exact same WebApplication via IIS UI and I'm able to browse to my WebApplication without `404 Error`.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I was using `c:/inetpub/wwwroot/previewapp` with `/` as separator. I switched to `\` separator and it works as expected now. Final path look like `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\previewapp`.